# Nested resource route helper not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a nested route like so:

```
  resources :apps do
    resources :issues
  end
```

the helper for seeing all issues related to an app is as follows:

```
app_issues_url(app)
```

but now I want to use a helper to point to a specific issue of a specific app like apps/1/issues/1 but i don't know how to use that helper. what is the helper for this url?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can pass both instances to url helper like

```
app_issue_url(@app,@issue)
```

you can also use

```
app_issue_path(@app,@issue)
```

or

```
url_for([@app,@issue])
```

see [rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) for more info