# How to link_to a show page from another MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, feed, link-to

I get this error when I pull up http://0.0.0.0:3000/activities:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ActivitiesController#index Couldn't
>   find Valuation with 'id'=
>   Line: `@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])`

**activities_controller**

```
def index
  @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page])
  @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
end
```

**activities/index**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
<% end %>
```

**activities/valuations/_create**

```
added value
  <%= activity.created_at.strftime('%B %d at %l:%M%P') %>
  <%= link_to activity.trackable.name, valuation_path(@valuation) %> #Trying to Fix This
```

The goal is so that when users are looking at the activities feed they can click on a activity and be directed to that respective valuation's show page, which is where they can like or comment on it.

**routes**

```
resources :activities do
  resources :valuations
end
```

Please let me know if you need any further explanation or code to help you help me otherwise here's the **[gist of it](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/d09f61e09dece645a60b)** :)

**development.log**

```
    Started GET "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-03 14:14:49 -0400
Processing by ActivitiesController#index as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mHabit Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36mValuation Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 11ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Valuation with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:4:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (126.4ms)


Started GET "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-03 14:14:50 -0400
Processing by ActivitiesController#index as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mHabit Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36mValuation Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Valuation with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:4:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.rc3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (35.2ms)
```

Comment: sir.. show the rails development.log file content from the console

Comment: what about changing "valuation_path(@valuation)" for "valuation_path(@valuation.id)". You are passing the whole @valuation as a parameter.

Comment: this path is wrong.. show the result of `rake routes`.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com your path should be like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207644/nested-resource-route-helper-not-working)

Comment: If I leave in activities index `@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])` I still get the same error @Hugo. If I take it out that would give me `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id]) needs an "id" parameter and You are not passing it. Check in the logs: "WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]".  You need to pass the ID parameter.

Comment: @R_O_R thank you! I used `<%= link_to activity.trackable.name, activity_valuation_path(@activity, @valuation) %>` but when I go to the activity feed now where the `activity.trackable.name` should be is now blank

Comment: @R_O_R I added that line above, but now where it use to show `activity.trackable.name` in the activities feed it doesn't show anything. It's blank, empty, gone, nothing to click. Maybe it's because I had to remove `@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])` to get rid of the error

Comment: hire me!!! :p I am still not getting you.. _gone_ means...?

Comment: It did not find any Valuation, because you did not pass the "id" as a parameter.

Comment: @Hugo maybe you can explain it better to R_O_R lol I'm trying to fix the params like you suggested. I tried `@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:valuation_id])` but same error. How can I pass this ID parameter?! I tried: `def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:valuation_id)
  end`

Comment: If you can help me further @Hugo I'm offering a bounty. Thanks kind sir :)

Comment: What is the relationship between Activity and Valuation? I see no relationship in the model. Your resource design tells us that valuation is like a child of activity. The activity-controller index method suggest the opposite: in the list of activities, you seem to want to display a single valuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link_to your show page with the code I understand you having you need to

1. `resources :activities do
     resources :valuations
   end`
2. Since it's polymorpic use trackable to find the id and put the line: `<%= link_to activity.trackable.name, activity_valuation_path(activity, activity.trackable_id) %>`
3. Take this line out from your index: `@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])`

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you got nested resources:

```
resources :activities do
  resources :valuations
end
```

this does not create the method

> valuation_path()

it creates

> activities_valuation_path()

if you want to create the valuation path you need to refactor to:

```
resources :activities do
  resources :valuations
end
resources :valuations            # this will create your method
```

or if the valuation is strongly connected to an activity i recommend using

> activities_valuation_path(:activity_id, :valuation_id)